# i want the typewriter effect like the website i have given link

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

i want to like this
[image: First full text comes "Search For right painter"]

1: First full text comes "Search For right painter"

You can see the example here http://www.helpedby.ca/

Than only  that white thing changes [image: like plumber,contractor,etc]

You can see the example here http://www.helpedby.ca/

i tried alot  but i cant change the last word like painter, plumber, carpenter and all i just want to change last words like that website.. using j query  Thank You in Advance

Comment: Here is where you can learn http://codepen.io/naibaf/pen/biJHg next time you post a question do your research.  Keep in mind this isn't a place to have programs made for free.  This is a community of programmers who help each other in a problem.  Your question shows that you haven't even attempted a means to solve this.  Come on man.

Comment: Also here is an example with erasing http://codepen.io/stathisg/pen/Bkvhg

Comment: @Rafael i tried a lot but i cant get that part all the thing gets typed but "Search For right painter" but after that only that part chages like plumber carpainter and all i want to know how to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you are searching jquery plugin like this
http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/

here is another  few plugins you might help

http://www.jqueryrain.com/?Rz1vxvW8

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Text-Typing-Effect-with-jQuery/

http://lea.verou.me/2011/09/pure-css3-typing-animation-with-steps/

```
i think this is you search
```

[this same as you search try](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Terminal-like-Text-Typing-Effect-with-jQuery-Teletype/)

download
http://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Terminal-like-Text-Typing-Effect-with-jQuery-Teletype.html